# How do I drop columns with index greater than x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have Excel sheets to read in as dataframes and load into Mongo. These Excel sheets are supposed to have 18 columns... but sometimes they have around 77 because someone was messing with it and forgot to delete their original copy paste.

I am not going through thousands of Excel sheets to clean them up.

I have been trying to get df.drop to do it for me, but apparently you can't tell it to drop columns with indexes greater than the size, which is an issue when your dataframes have size variances.

Trying to think...

```
if len(df.columns) > 18:
    extra = len - 18
    for i in range(extra):
        df = df.drop(df.columns[i + 17], axis = 1)
```

Seems like it should work?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `.iloc`

```
n=18 

df = df.iloc[:,:18]
```